# Flutter ios Build not working on MacOS Big Sur 11.0 Beta

Tags: xcode, flutter, macos-big-sur, flutter-ios

On MacOS BigSur Beta, I am trying to generate the build of iOS, but that is always giving me the following error.

I tried re-installing flutter, sitching to beta, dev or master and use of Xcode beta as well but nothing worked.

help me if anyone faced same issue and resolve that.

[image]

```
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/json-2.3.1/ext/json/ext/generator
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200926-66152-11vu3z5.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/json-2.3.1/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/json-2.3.1/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from generator.c:1:
In file included from ./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby.h:33:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found
#include "ruby/config.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: note: did not find header 'config.h' in framework 'ruby' (loaded from '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks')
1 error generated.
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/json-2.3.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-20/2.6.0/json-2.3.1/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try installing old version cocoapods.

1. Uninstall cocoapods
2. install old version cocoapods (e.g. 1.8.0)`sudo gem install cocoapods --version '=1.8.0' -n /usr/local/bin`
3. flutter clean
4. pub get
5. run your project (iOS simulator)

I resolved the error using this procedure.

Comment: Is there any problem or change for flutter with macOs Big Sur?